# Evaluating $\mathcal{P}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + a^2x^2)(x^2 - b^2)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

I am trying to evaluate this integral 
$$\mathcal{P}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + a^2x^2)(x^2 - b^2)}$$
with $\mathcal{P}$ the principal value and $a,b>0$.

I already know the answer to be $$ - \frac{a\pi}{2(1 + a^2b^2)}$$
after fiddling with Mathematica putting numbers for $a$ and $b$.

The poles of this function are at $x=\pm b, \pm \frac{i}{a^2}$ so I cannot find a proper contour.

Any help in getting the answer will be appreciated!

Comment: Your answer shouldn't be $x$-dependent; I assume that's a typo.

Comment: Yes --' I updated it

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can take the following contour: (ignore the orange dashed lines for now)
[image]

Why I think it works-

- All residues are computable
- the integral along the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ line goes to 0 for large radius $R\to\infty$, since the integrand is like $R^{-4}$.
- The integral along the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ parts gives twice your answer, since the integral is an even function of $x$ (since $x^2 = (-x)^2$)
- The integral along both the $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ semicircles around $\pm b$ is actually equal to the integral along both the $\color{orange}{\text{orange}}$ contours, due to the same symmetry as the above bullet point (180º rotation, $z^2 = (-z)^2$). So they are half the residues at $\pm b$.

Therefore, setting $f(z) := \frac1{(1 + a^2z^2)(z^2 - b^2)}$,

$$ 2\mathcal{P}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + a^2x^2)(x^2 - b^2)} = 2\pi i \left( \operatorname{Res}(f;i/a) + \frac12 \operatorname{Res}(f;-b) + \frac12 \operatorname{Res}(f;b) \right) $$

The rest of it should be easy. [The partial fraction decomposition](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions++1%2F((1%2Ba%5E2x%5E2)(x%5E2+-+b%5E2))) 
$$\frac1{(1 + a^2z^2)(b^2 - x^2)} =  \frac{-a^2}{(a^2 b^2 + 1) (a^2 x^2 + 1)} + \frac1{2 b (a^2 b^2 + 1) (x - b)} - \frac1{2 b (a^2 b^2 + 1) (b + x)}
$$should be useful.

Comment: Thank you Calvin, it was extremely helpful. There is just one minus sign missing before the first term of the partial decomposition.

Comment: @Fuoar Glad to help. I have corrected that now

Answer (score 1):

Use that $$\frac{1}{(1+a^2x^2)(x^2-b^2)}=1/2\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 1+{a}^{2}{b}^{2} \right) b \left( -b+x
 \right) }}-{\frac {{a}^{2}}{ \left( 1+{a}^{2}{b}^{2} \right)  \left( 
1+{a}^{2}{x}^{2} \right) }}-1/2\,{\frac {1}{ \left( 1+{a}^{2}{b}^{2}
 \right) b \left( b+x \right) }}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to both of you for the help!

So indeed, this contour is a good one to evaluate this integral.

The residues at $b$ and $-b$ just cancel each other.
The residue at $i/a$ gives $$ - \frac{a}{2i\left( a^2 b^2 +1 \right)}$$
Thus we have
$$ 2\mathcal{P}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + a^2x^2)(x^2 - b^2)} = 2\pi i \left(- \frac{a}{2i\left( a^2 b^2 +1 \right)} \right) =  \frac{-\pi a}{1 + a^2b^2}$$
$$ \mathcal{P}\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1 + a^2x^2)(x^2 - b^2)} = -\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{a}{1 + a^2b^2}$$